# Reducing a symmetric matrix to upper Hessenberg form using Householder transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

[Iteration step of the Householder transformation upper Hessenberg form of a symmetric matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f6xu.png)

Hi, I have a question which aims at calculating a vector z such that the following relation holds:

$$A - \beta vv^TA - \beta Avv^T + \beta^2vv^TAvv^T = A - vz^T - zv^T$$

My way of doing this was by trying to "associate" things, in the following way ($A$ is short for $A(k + 1 : n; k + 1 : n)$ ):

$$A - \beta vv^TA - \beta Avv^T - \beta^2vv^TAvv^T = 
A - v(\beta v^TA - \beta^2v^TAvv^T) - (\beta Av)v^T$$

where $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, $v \in \mathbb{R^{n\times1}}$, $A \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ and z is a vector of unknown dimensions.

By doing this, I aknowledged $z = \beta Av$ and $z^T = \beta v^TA + \beta^2v^TAvv^T$.

Afterwards, I decided to equate both zs:

$\beta v^TA^T = \beta v^TA + \beta^2v^TAvv^T$

And I was stuck. Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a modifictation of $A$ that in the range contains the vectors $v$ and $Av$, thus is a rank-2 update. Thus the general ansatz is $z=av+bAv$. Now insert this
$$
A-βvv^TA-βAvv^T+β^2(v^TAv)vv^T=A-avv^T-bAvv^T-avv^T-bvv^TA
$$
Thus $b=β$ and $2a=-β^2(v^TAv)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One question, isn't $\displaystyle{a = \frac{β^2(vv^TAvv^T)}{2}}$? Or have I miscalculated something?

Comment: You have a sign error in the expansion of $(I-βvv^T)A(I-βvv^T)$. Note that the middle term $v^TAv$ is a scalar, while the remaining dyadic product $vv^T$ is a rank-1 matrix.